# Does each universe has different Veda?

Tags: vedas, creation, universe

It is said that from Brahman uncountable universes are emanated. Every Multiverse has different Brahma. Something like following image. My question is do these multiverses have same Veda or different?

[image: Multiverse]

Comment: Parabrahma is the same for all the universes but the creator Brahma, Indra and other devatas are different. Vedas give the knowledge of Parabrahma who is the same for all universes. I think vedas should be the same.